# Does SO Portuguese have more downvotes than SO English?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, english, portuguese-stackoverflow

Is it just me or has anyone else noticed that SO Portuguese often has more downvotes than SO English? Further, is there a way for us to find data to test this hypothesis?

If this is true, I wonder why that happens. For sure we have a different community but I wonder if it is because people are more critical in SO Portuguese, or because the questions in SO Portuguese are indeed worse on average.

Comment: Would one having more downvotes than the other, present some kind of problem?

Comment: I meant ratio. @Glorfindel manage to show me the data. Thanks

Comment: If the proportion of downvotes is too big, then it would indicate “something” about that community. I don’t think it would indicate a problem per se. But would indicate something. And that is what I was trying to understand. However, it seems my hypothesis was going in the opposite direction.

Comment: hmm... I thought you expected the SO Portuguese to have less upvotes per downvote, it's currently sitting at nearly 3 upvotes per downvote, where as SO English is 7.6, isn't that confirming?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily indicate that people are more ciritical there, rather, it likely indicates more people find the content on SO English useful than those who don't.

Comment: Hum… Would that be all @KevinB? or could we see something else there that describes the community interaction? (genuine question). Of course, this could just be a random finding, and it may change with time.

Comment: you gotta look at how voting actually occurs, and how the community sees voting in general. upvoting something requires having 10 rep to begin with, and downvoting requires having 125 rep. Both of these thresholds are ones that ordinary users don't achieve, however, when you look at the number of users on one site vs the other, one is vastly larger, and therefore the likelyhood of a given user having the rep to upvote is much higher.

Comment: On a smaller site, like SO Portuguese, the user pool is smaller, the number of voters are smaller, less people are earning the rep to vote, so it's much easier for content-quality conscious users ensure low quality content is getting downvoted.

Comment: Looking at the data you can certainly argue there's more to the picture, given there's also small sites with similar ratios to SO, though... at a certain point a site is probably too small to draw any useful conclusions, as they're looking for any and all questions so they can grow. SO English too was far less strict in it's early days

Comment: IMO the data point you are lacking at the moment is the number of posts per site that accompanies the number of upvotes vs downvotes.  SO having more  upvotes per downvote doesn’t necessarily indicate that it’s questions receive more upvotes each

Comment: English Stack Overflow has existed for more than 10 years and went through many experiences and changing rules/policies. The raw data might be skewed since [there are many highly upvoted questions that were posted back then but are closed now](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3A1+duplicate%3A0&searchOn=3). If those questions are asked now, they will receive a flurry of downvotes instead.

Answer (score 18):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can provide some insight. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1559724/up-downvotes) shows the ratio between up- and downvotes on Portuguese Stack Overflow is 2.5 lower than on the English site, and how the other Stack Overflow sites are faring:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I think that answers my question, and disprove my hypothesis. Thanks!

Comment: @RuamPimentel does it disprove it? It shows that on the Portuguese site, for every 3 upvotes, there is one downvote. In other words, 2 out of 8 votes (25%) are downvotes. On the English site, for every 7.5 upvotes, there is one down vote. In other words, 2 out of 15 (11%) votes are downvotes. This shows that the sentiment is much more negative on the Portuguese site. That seems to support your hypothesis.

Comment: @Glorfindel, I forked your query and modified it a little bit to show the percentage of negative votes instead of the ratio up/down. It think the percentage is a bit more intuitive. Feel free to use: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1559763

Comment: Hum… I see it now @DeltaLima. Thanks for clarifying this interpretation. Yes, the percentage it a bit more intuitive. Now I come back to the main question then. What could that imply for the SO Portuguese community?

Comment: @RuamPimentel simply said, it says that in the Portuguese SO community there are more downvotes being cast. But it doesn't say anything more than that. It could be that there are more poorly formulated posts, or factually wrong answers on the Portuguese site. It could also mean that the Portuguese speaking community is more direct and open to show disagreement with a post than the English/international community. In other words, it can be a matter of quality or culture, or both.

Comment: @DeltaLima good suggestion, I think both figures work fine but apparently I'm in the minority :)